# Truly strictly typed API workflow - How to write robust API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, rest

I tried a lot of different tools and frameworks, I wanted to use something. Truly strictly typed with Nodejs and Typescript but It seems nothing really is ?

For example, the routing system :

I've tried frameworks like Meteor and NestJS, those frameworks are really hard to extend, if a feature is missing you will never be able to develop something on top of it while keeping everything typed.

I've got my hands on frameworks like Nuxt, Next & Sapper. But nothing is really typed, or in a weird way.

So I went for Express JS, I can type my own routes and write my own methods and class to extend it. It's easier than anything else I tried before.

But the routing system is only one part of a working API. Now I need to link my routes with my database, and, of course, I need to take an ORM with me. But event TypeORM or Sequelize-Typescript are not truly typed. Some methods like "`User.create({//Not typed})`" from sequelize-typescript don't provide custom types to help me fill this method.

And after the ORM, it will be the turn of the authentication, the data inputs, or even the client side.

Typescript is awesome, but everything that "use typescript" will still have some layer of dynamic data that need to be checked manually when writing the code.

How do you handle this ? Do you always check your types and interfaces in your secondary screen when you are making your application ? When you need to add a new field inside an interface, how do you keep track of every part of your application using it (routes, clients, databases, validation) ?

I just don't want to start writing my API only to find that it's hard to modify, improve or debug (I will probably have more than 25 entities with more than 100 relations between them).

Comment: You cannot, and I mean **cannot**, do what you want. It has failed [over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#:~:text=XML%2DRPC%20is%20a%20remote,HTTP%20as%20a%20transport%20mechanism.) and [over](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl.html) and [over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) and [over](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1142044)... there's a reason we don't do that. You can pick (assuming you get a choice) a protocol with a schema (avro, protocol buffers, XML with DTD) so you know what you're getting, and that's about as close as you can get. But you ...

Comment: ...will always have to deal with messy, sparse, unruly data. You are going to have to normalize it, always. You are going to have to often deal with 3rd party APIs, that may or may not share your view of what constitutes safety, or what the API contract means, or whether or not adding a key in a data structure is/should count as a breaking change. That being said, this is an opinion question, and not a good fit for SO.

Comment: TypeScript is not a runtime type system. It's a dev-time utility to remind you of your object schemas and function signatures. By the time your code is running, it's PURE JS. Keep in mind that TypeScript is an "erasable" syntax, which means it vanishes when you compile your code.

Comment: That said, I've come to utilize and enjoy this library to check whether an object (for example a request payload I receive in an API call) matches the expected interface. https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your TypeORM entities typesafe by defining a model and including it in the schema definition (from: https://typeorm.io/#/separating-entity-definition)

```
import {EntitySchema} from "typeorm";

export interface Category {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export const CategoryEntity = new EntitySchema<Category>({
    name: "category",
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: Number,
            primary: true,
            generated: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What about wires?

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't think I know what "wires" are. Can you give an example?

Comment: In this case I mean literal physical wires like your ISP uses. So you've got your express app with your strongly-typed ORM interface to your database and then some webpage or mobile app or other service hits it with an HTTP request. How do you type that? N.B. those other things may be written in completely different languages with completely different type systems.

Comment: Use DTO's in your local app to map API types to local types.

Comment: Again, there is no automatic universal general purpose way to use them. It's all on **you,** the developer. You have to *explicitly* map types, sometimes between disparate type systems. Also again, *that presumes you have control over the API*. You frequently don't. And since you already have to have bespoke mechanisms for ingesting and normalizing messy sparse inconsistent data... is it worth the effort? Is it worth the tradeoffs? If you're consuming an API that I wrote that gives you a k/v structure, and I *add* a key, should your code break? As I linked repeatedly in my comment...

Comment: ...on the question, the Path of History is littered with the skulls of systems that attempted to maintain strong typing over wires. I mean, I use Typescript as much or more often than Javascript, and I frequently add type annotations to my backend Python code, and I contribute to an open source hardware emulation project in C++, so obviously I like static analysis. I just don't try to push it beyond it's limits.

Comment: @JaredSmith Typescript's typing system is only dev time tooling. Typing just gives you convenience when writing your code because you've declared your expected type (whether or not it is the actual type). It still compiles to regular JS and runs as JS. So, the answer to your example actually depends on JS behavior. In the case of adding a key, your code will not likely break. In the case of removing a key, however, you may get errors for undefined references if you were actually using those keys in your code (notwithstanding type definitions).

Comment: As to whether it is worth it or not, I guess only you can answer that question depending on your circumstances. For projects that I work on, I consume API's that are written mostly in-house. So, if we keep our project references up to date, then we can find errors at compile time if/when type definitions change.